# Unable to extend access token duration: unknown path component error

Tags: authentication, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to extend my short duration access tokens using the client side oath approach in scenario 4 of the "removal of offline_access permission" document. After I get my short duration access token I make a call to

https://graph.facebook.com/oath/access_token?client_id=&client_secret=&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=

what I get back is an error

Unknown path component: \access_token

I can't figure out what is wrong, what I'm doing looks to me just like the example.

Answer (score 2):

You've misspelled 'oauth' as 'oath'

Comment: Thanks!!! I looked at the spelling over and over but my brain just could not register that.